# How did IKEA design evolve?

Tags: everyday-life, contemporary-history

How did [IKEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKEA) develop the characteristic style?  I know there is a catalog each year, but I'm looking more for a summary and overview of the design evolution.
I understand it's not as significant as, for example, Braun's design for which a design [history article exists](http://www.core77.com/blog/braun/a_history_of_braun_design_part_1_electric_shavers_24437.asp). Nonetheless IKEA is a term many are familiar with and the furniture is found in many urban homes (at least in Europe).

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but interesting nonetheless: [How has Ikea changed furniture design?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-20125014)

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKEA#cite_note-32) is your friend: http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_AU/about_ikea/the_ikea_way/history/ ...

Comment: The BBC link in the comments looks like something I'm looking for, only then in a book/article form. The history link of the IKEA website is just a brief timeline of the company. It does mention the introduction of certain products, but is very brief and does not place inside the design history context. So unfortunately the latter is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: To my knowledge there are a variety of books related to IKEA for example, the following: _Ikea the Book_; _The IKEA Edge_; and _Leading By Design_. But many of these are business related. _IKEA the Book_ is probably your most promising source. Although the question you pose is ripe for  independent research. It seems like enough material for a decent sized book.

Comment: The question gets periodically re-examined in meta; if you desire to change it, I think that is the right place to start. I think this question could be within scope with relatively minor edits; I will make an attempt.

Comment: [Discussion in meta](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/896/1401) I respectfully ask that a mod remove all the comments that should be addressed to the meta conversation.

Answer (score 4):

Check [Harvard Business Review](http://hbr.org/search/ikea/0). I've bought their "IKEA and Ingvar Kamprad" and "IKEA Invades America" articles (each are about $5) which both include information regarding some of their earlier approaches to design.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the articles? Using the search function of HBR yields nothing... It will also make your answer more useful for future visitors.

Comment: Check this query http://hbr.org/search/ikea/0
let me know if it still doesn't work. You might need to register first.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Strangely when I just use the search field [this](http://hbr.org/?term=ikea&search.x=-781&search.y=-57) is the result (a general page, with links to most popular articles).